# conditional union-execute second query if first doesnt return rows

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I have a mysql query as below:

```
select m.field1, l.field2... l.fieldn
from mytable m, logtable l
where <some conditions to join m and l>

union

select m.field1, h.field2... h.fieldn
from mytable m, loghistorytable h
where <some conditions to join m and h>
```

Now since history table is quite huge and hits performance, i want to execute the second select from history only if the current log table doesn't return data. Can i modify the query somehow?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why not simply execute query 1. If no result, execute query 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repeat first query in second query's condition as below:

```
select m.field1, l.field2... l.fieldn
from mytable m, logtable l
where <some conditions to join m and l>

union

select m.field1, h.field2... h.fieldn
from mytable m, loghistorytable h
where <some conditions to join m and h>
and not exists (select m.field1, l.field2... l.fieldn
                from mytable m, logtable l
                where <some conditions to join m and l>)
```